# Clear chatterbot database

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Chatterbot (http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/) for a simple chat AI, but I have a few problems.

I'm trying to create my own database for it. But it seems that it has it cached somewhere, I can't clear it's database to completely replace it with my own questions\answers it just keeps using old ones. And new ones too.

```
chatbot = ChatBot("botName")
chatbot.set_trainer(ChatterBotCorpusTrainer)

# Train based on the english corpus
#chatbot.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")
#chatbot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)


file = codecs.open(os.path.join(realPath, 'data', 'skynet.json'), encoding='utf-8')
jsonData = json.load(file)

for value in jsonData.values():
    for conv in value:
        tm = []
        for line in conv:
            tm.append(line)
        print (tm)
        chatbot.train (conv)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, stupid me. The file 'database.db' was under my nose, in the same folder as my python file.

Comment: I had this program yesterday. I googled and googled and couldn't figure it out. Then I saw the database file and was like "Duh!" lol. I just came across this page today while looking for prebuilt databases. Funny.

Comment: Just curious, @Nix, would you be willing to share your database.db file? I am just looking for a quick solution to get a little more manners/personality out of my bot, but I'm finding this to be a very time consuming pursuit. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I did not train it yet that much. And my db is in Russian anyway. And I switched to using MongoDB instead, it's way faster than using json.db file, and relatively easy to setup. You just install it, and then run an exe file with a path to where you want your db stored, I do it from my python script, before the chatbot is initialized. I also wrote a script to gather dialogues from vk.com and facebook and turn it into train data, but that was a bad idea :D

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this command to reset the databse -

```
chatbot = ChatBot("botName")
chatbot.storage.drop()
```

Next time you run the code, chatterbot will start with a new database, Make sure the stroage.drop() you use only once (not everytime) otherwise you will end up testing bot with empty database every time.

Comment: OK, the DB is cleared, but why did the file size remain the same?